# Зацикленность Java

Tags: java

Не понимаю почему цикл зацикливается,
объясните пожалуйста

```
for (byte i = 126; i<=127; i++) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

При этом когда делаю не менее ровное а просто меньше (i <127), все в порядке

Comment: Потому-что в последний момент переменная `i++` выходит за пределы (-128, 127) и стает равна `-128`, почему и собственно далее снова цикл считает по кругу, -127, -126 и тд.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

byte имеет значения от -128 до 127. Поэтому 127+1 даёт -128 и условие <=127 всегда истинно.